# Why is order int.MaxValue - 10 used for IOrderedFilter and which order to use for additional filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to implement an additional filter into an ASP.NET Core 6 based web application. Right now, there is already a filter implemented which handles certain http exceptions in `OnActionExecuted`. This filter implements the `IOrderedFilter` interface and has its `Order` defined like this:

```
public int Order => int.MaxValue - 10;
```

The new filter which I want to implement should run right before the code inside the controller actions is executed. Now I have two questions about this:

1. Why is `int.MaxValue - 10` used for the first filter? I've also seen this same way of specifying the order in a few examples on various sites but I do not understand why exactly anyone would use this exact number. Is there any reason for this?
2. Which order should I use for my new filter? Or does that not matter because, unlike the other filter, it should execute before the controller actions?

Comment: A search yielded [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19281) which led to [this commit](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/commit/0646aea3591ffa596b89239824a3c3a17e9c1992). I'm not 100% sure if this is the same thing you're talking about though?

Comment: @Llama Yes, it is the same thing but the explanation still sounds a little confusing to me. Why does subtracting 10 allow other filters to run at the very end of the pipeline?

Comment: I think it means that filters can be placed at `int.MaxValue - 9`, `int.MaxValue - 8`, `int.MaxValue - 7`, etc.

Comment: I think the comment is trying to say that using `int.MaxValue - 10` will cause it to run at the end, but still allow something else to run after it. Seems pretty hacky to me...

Comment: @MatthewWatson It seems like quite  hacky approach indeed.

Comment: Wow, I must have read that wrong like at least three or four times! Yeah, it seems like this is just done to allow other filters to be executed after the filter. I always read and understood it like this means that it does **not** allow other filters to run after this filter. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: too tricky, they should explain that in more detailed way